# How to output fetch request response in react native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I want to print out the response of my fetch request in react native.

How would I do this to get the response inside a Text?

```
function Nft() {
  fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd"
  );
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={style.header}>Bitcoin Price</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Nft;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define state variable like following

```
const[price,setPrice]=useState(0);
```

then replace fetch code by following

```
 fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price? ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd')
 .then((res)=>res.json())
 .then((response)=>{
    //your response is like this ,{"bitcoin":{"usd":18993.39}}  
   let price= response?.bitcoin?.usd;  
   setPrice(price)

 })
 .catch((error)=>{
      //here you can manage errors 
 })
```

**In your component you can right in this way**

```
<Text>{price}<Text>
```

Comment: it doesnt print out anything

Comment: i think you did mistake in your code. its very basic syntax you can do your own way.

Comment: thanks it worked, i had a typo in my url

Comment: how would i update the price: setTimeout(() => {
        setPrice(price)
      }, 120000);

Comment: it works after 120 seconds.

Comment: no it desnt, how can i turn the whole fetch thing into a function so I can return the price? and than I need to fetch the new price every 120 seconds, here i only recheck the price variable every 120 seconds

Comment: simple thing add your fetch code in function and where i set a sate from there return price

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following code

```
 fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price? ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd')
 .then((res)=>res.json())
 .then((response)=>{
     //here you can get your output of fetch in the response variable
     //whatever data you want to show here save in state variable and 
     //use that state variable to display.

 })
 .catch((error)=>{
      //here you can manage errors 
 })
```

**In your component you can right in this way

```
<Text>{your state variable}<Text>
```

Comment: i want to print out the price on the UI, i get the price from the api

Comment: then save the price in a state if its an array of prices then using a map or flat list you can print all price values which you get in the array.

Comment: can you post an example, all examples on google are with flat list but i only want to print out the price

Comment: yes, I posted a new answer you can check it.

Comment: can you not write a better answer? 
where do i get the state variable from, because if i put fetch in a function i get , functions arent valid as react child

Comment: ok let me edit again

Comment: check new answer